# Div (contains list of items) not close when clicked outside

Tags: vue.js

Please open https://jsfiddle.net/gfmyt9u8/31/

***When user clicks outside `<section>` tag area, then the opened div overlay panel should be closed.***

**Steps to produce scenario** :

- Click "Please Select Options"
- Now, click first item from opened overlay panel (by doing this, the panel got closed automatically)
- Next, Click inside the blue color border div (This shows "Please Select Options" as label) again
- Now, try to click outside the "*blue color border div*" and "*opened div overlay panel beneath"* both
- overlay panel will not close

**Actual Result** : overlay panel is not closing

**Expected Result** : overlay panel should close when clicked outside the "blue color border div" and "open overlay panel 
 beneath"

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mounted` lifecycle hook to add a click event listener to check if the click event is outside the element or not, and based on that hide the element.

**A working example:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    displayList: false,
    cat: ['A', 'B']
  },
  methods: {
    itemSelect(o) {
      this.displayList = false;
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    
    // Listen to all clicks on the document
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    
      // If the click inside the element, do nothing
      if (event.target.closest(".section-main")) return;

      // If the clicks outside the element, hide it!
      this.displayList = false;

    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.display-no-selected {  
  cursor: text;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid 2px blue;
}
.display-list {
  border: solid 1px wheat;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.toggle-list {
  display: none;
}
ul, .selected-ul {
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
ul.inner-ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul.inner-ul li:hover {
  background-color: wheat;
}
.default-highlight {
  background-color: wheat;
}
ul.inner-ul li span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <section class="section-main">
  <div class="display-no-selected" @click="displayList=true"> Please Select Options 
  </div>
  <div class="display-list"
       v-bind:class="{'toggle-list': !displayList}">
    <ul class="inner-first-ul inner-ul">
      <li v-for="o in cat" @click="itemSelect(o)">
        <span>{{o}}</span>              
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can this  be handle using vue instead of javascript.